# PROBLEMAS CON CORS AL QUERER ENVIAR A MI LOCALHOST

Tags: php, cors, headers

Quiero enviar datos desde un js ejecutado desde chrome a mi un php en mi localhost de xampp sin html, pero al momento de hacerlo se bloquea por los CORS y en mi código php he estado cambiando de headers y ninguno me funciona.

Actualmente así es como tengo los headers pero tampoco me deja y ya cree un archivo ".HTACCESS" y le he cambiado el contenido varias veces y nada

```
header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" );
header('Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es con el `Preflight`  que las peticiones hacen  para ver los opciones disponibles.

Te recomiendo utilizar el siguiente código

```
<?php
#asi evitamos  los errores de CORS
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    die();
}
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');


//Aqui el resto de tu codigo

?>
```

Si el `metodo` de `request` es `OPTIONS` es muy muy importante `terminar el script` para que este no continue, por eso el `die();`

recuerda comentar esta lineal si  no la necesitas

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```